# Webflux returning Mono and using info in Object in Mono to set header

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Let's say my Webflux handler returns a Mono on a product creation
That's easy to do.

But now, I want to complete the response with a `location` in the header.
To do so, I need to get the created product ID.

In my example, I used a `block()` which fails the reactive idea of the handler.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> handleRequest(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        ...
        Mono<Product> monoProduct = // Service call to get the Mono<Product>
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                             .location(URI.create(String.format("/api/products/%s",
                                                                monoProduct.block().getId()))))
                             .body(monoProduct), ProductResponse.class);
    }
```

How can I perform such a task without breaking the reactive principles?

Comment: Remind you that the mono tag is for something else. Do study each tags before using.

Comment: Not sure to follow @LexLi ...
I'm using a Mono because my service can only return 1 element

Comment: In short, use the java tag.

Comment: Ok, I finally got what you meant.
The question tags!!
Yeah you right. Thanx for editing the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to block. You need to build reactive flow combining different operators.

In your case it could look like

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> handleRequest(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return getProduct() // Service call to get the Mono<Product>
            .map(product -> mapToResponse(product)) // Product -> ProductResponse
            .flatMap(response ->
                    ServerResponse.ok()
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .location(URI.create(String.format("/api/products/%s", response.getId())))
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(response))
            );
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Alex.
I knew I didn't need to block, Blocking was not an option by the way.
It was just to show that I was stuck in the wrong path and blocking was the only option here.
Flat mapping was the right path that I should have taken instead of the one I took